# Unable to save image paths to database yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-xupload

I am using the xupload extension, which is based on the blueimp jquery fileuploader, and while I can successfully upload to the folder, I am unable to add the paths and other details to the database. Below is the upload action and the model, in that order. Please help. Thanks.

```
public function actionUpload( ) {
//Here we define the paths where the files will be stored temporarily
$path = Yii::app() -> getBasePath() . "/../images/";
$publicPath = Yii::app()->getBaseUrl( )."/images/";

//This is for IE which doens't handle 'Content-type: application/json' correctly
header( 'Vary: Accept' );
if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] ) 
    && (strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'application/json' ) !== false) ) {
    header( 'Content-type: application/json' );
} else {
    header( 'Content-type: text/plain' );
}

//Here we check if we are deleting and uploaded file
if( isset( $_GET["_method"] ) ) {
    if( $_GET["_method"] == "delete" ) {
        if( $_GET["file"][0] !== '.' ) {
            $file = $path.$_GET["file"];
            if( is_file( $file ) ) {
                unlink( $file );
            }
        }
        echo json_encode( true );
    }
} else {
    $model = new Photo;
    $model->file = CUploadedFile::getInstance( $model, 'file' );
    //We check that the file was successfully uploaded
    if( $model->file !== null ) {
        //Grab some data
        $model->mime_type = $model->file->getType( );
        //$model->size = $model->file->getSize( );
        $model->name = $model->file->getName( );
        //(optional) Generate a random name for our file
        $filename = md5( Yii::app( )->user->id.microtime( ).$model->name);
        $filename .= ".".$model->file->getExtensionName( );
        if( $model->validate( ) ) {
            //Move our file to our temporary dir
            $model->file->saveAs( $path.$filename );
            chmod( $path.$filename, 0777 );
            //$model -> path = "/images/uploads/".$filename;

            //here you can also generate the image versions you need 
            //using something like PHPThumb



            //Now we need to save this path to the user's session
            if( Yii::app( )->user->hasState( 'images' ) ) {
                $userImages = Yii::app( )->user->getState( 'images' );
            } else {
                $userImages = array();
            }
             $userImages[] = array(
                "path" => $path.$filename,
                //the same file or a thumb version that you generated
                "thumb" => $path.$filename,
                "filename" => $filename,
                'size' => $model->size,
                'mime' => $model->mime_type,
                'name' => $model->name,
            );
            Yii::app( )->user->setState( 'images', $userImages );

            //Now we need to tell our widget that the upload was succesfull
            //We do so, using the json structure defined in
            // https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup
            echo json_encode( array( array(
                    "name" => $model->name,
                    "type" => $model->mime_type,
                    "size" => $model->size,
                    "url" => $publicPath.$filename,
                    "thumbnail_url" => $publicPath."thumbs/$filename",
                    "delete_url" => $this->createUrl( "upload", array(
                        "_method" => "delete",
                        "file" => $filename
                    ) ),
                    "delete_type" => "POST"
                ) ) );

        } else {
            //If the upload failed for some reason we log some data and let the widget know
            echo json_encode( array( 
                array( "error" => $model->getErrors( 'file' ),
            ) ) );
            Yii::log( "XUploadAction: ".CVarDumper::dumpAsString( $model->getErrors( ) ),
                CLogger::LEVEL_ERROR, "xupload.actions.XUploadAction" 
            );
        }
    } else {
        throw new CHttpException( 500, "Could not upload file" );
    }
}
}
```

and the model;

```
<?php
class Photo extends CFormModel
{
public $file;
public $mime_type;
public $size;
public $name;
public $filename;


public function tableName()
{
    return 'photo';
}

public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

public function rules()
{
        return array(
                array('file', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg,gif,html'),
        );
}

/**
 * Declares attribute labels.
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
        return array(
                'file'=>'Upload files',
        );
}

public function getReadableFileSize($retstring = null) {
        // adapted from code at http://aidanlister.com/repos/v/function.size_readable.php
        $sizes = array('bytes', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB');

        if ($retstring === null) { $retstring = '%01.2f %s'; }

        $lastsizestring = end($sizes);

        foreach ($sizes as $sizestring) {
                if ($this->size < 1024) { break; }
                if ($sizestring != $lastsizestring) { $this->size /= 1024; }
        }
        if ($sizestring == $sizes[0]) { $retstring = '%01d %s'; } // Bytes aren't normally fractional
        return sprintf($retstring, $this->size, $sizestring);
}

/**
 * A stub to allow overrides of thumbnails returned
 * @since 0.5
 * @author acorncom
 * @return string thumbnail name (if blank, thumbnail won't display)
 */
public function getThumbnailUrl($publicPath) {
    return $publicPath.$this->filename;
}

public function afterSave()
{
    $this->addPhotos();
    parent::afterSave();
}

public function addPhotos()
{
    if(Yii::app()->user->hasState('images')){
        $userImages = Yii::app()->user->getState('images');
        $path = Yii::app()->getBasePath."/../images/uploads/";
        if(!is_dir($path)){
            mkdir($path);
            chmod($path, 0777);
        }

        foreach($userImages as $image){
            if(is_file($image['path'])){
                if(rename($image['path'], $path.$image['filename'])){
                    chmod($path.$image['filename'], 0777);
                    $photo = new Photo;
                    //$photo -> size = $image['size'];
                    //$photo -> mime = $image['mime'];
                    $photo ->name = $image['name'];
                    $photo -> path = "/images/uploads/".$image['filename'];
                    if(!$photo->save()){
                        Yii::log(("Can't Save: \n").CVarDumper::dumpAsString($photo->getErrors()),CLogger::LEVEL_ERROR);
                        throw new Exception( "Could not save Image");
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                Yii::log($image['path']."is not a file", CLogger::LEVEL_WARNING);
            }
        }
        Yii::app()->user->setState('images', null);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Do you debug your code?

Comment: yes i did and there's no error

Comment: Do you can show your SQL command with path of file?

Answer (score 1):

So turns out if I use Active Record, or the Query Builder, it doesn't work. So I have used SQL and it works. Here is the code:

```
public function actionPost( ) {
//Here we define the paths where the files will be stored temporarily
$path = Yii::app() -> getBasePath() . "/../images/";
$publicPath = Yii::app()->getBaseUrl( )."/images/";

//This is for IE which doens't handle 'Content-type: application/json' correctly
header( 'Vary: Accept' );
if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] ) 
    && (strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'application/json' ) !== false) ) {
    header( 'Content-type: application/json' );
} else {
    header( 'Content-type: text/plain' );
}

//Here we check if we are deleting and uploaded file
if( isset( $_GET["_method"] ) ) {
    if( $_GET["_method"] == "delete" ) {
        if( $_GET["file"][0] !== '.' ) {
            $query = "DELETE FROM `fuck`.`photo` WHERE `photo`.`path` = $file";
            $file = $path.$_GET["file"];
            if( is_file( $file ) ) {
                unlink( $file );
                Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->execute();
            }

        }
        echo json_encode( true );
    }
} else {
    $model = new Photo;

    $model->file = CUploadedFile::getInstance( $model, 'file' );
    //We check that the file was successfully uploaded
    if( $model->file !== null ) {
        //Grab some data
        $model->mime_type = $model->file->getType( );
        $model->size = $model->file->getSize( );
        $model->name = $model->file->getName( );
        //(optional) Generate a random name for our file
        $filename = md5( Yii::app( )->user->id.microtime( ).$model->name);
        $filename .= ".".$model->file->getExtensionName( );
        if( $model->validate( ) ) {
            //Move our file to our temporary dir
            $model->file->saveAs( $path.$filename );
            chmod( $path.$filename, 0777 );

            $drive = "/images/".$filename;
           /* $db->createCommand()->insert('photo', array(
            //'id'=>$newID,
            'name'=>$model->name,
            'path'=>$drive,
             )); */
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `gallery`.`photo` ( 
                                    `name` ,
                                    `path`
                                    )
                                    VALUES (
                                     '$model->name', '$drive'
                                    );

                                        ";
            Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();




            echo json_encode( array( array(
                    "name" => $model->name,
                    "type" => $model->mime_type,
                    "size" => $model->size,
                    "url" => $publicPath.$filename,
                    "thumbnail_url" => $publicPath."thumbs/$filename",
                    "delete_url" => $this->createUrl( "upload", array(
                        "_method" => "delete",
                        "file" => $filename
                    ) ),
                    "delete_type" => "POST"
                ) ) );

        } else {
            //If the upload failed for some reason we log some data and let the widget know
            echo json_encode( array( 
                array( "error" => $model->getErrors( 'file' ),
            ) ) );
            Yii::log( "XUploadAction: ".CVarDumper::dumpAsString( $model->getErrors( ) ),
                CLogger::LEVEL_ERROR, "xupload.actions.XUploadAction" 
            );
        }
    } else {
        throw new CHttpException( 500, "Could not upload file" );
    }

}
}
```